# Jquery Image Rotator clashing with Javascript Drop Down Menu

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get "Portraits" to Drop Down to three  more sub links. As you can see it pops up very subtly with each transition in the image rotation (the big circle). Also it's not lined up with the other links. However, I'm more concerned about it the drop down (first link in nav) clashing with the Jquery Cycle. For some reason it does not work when I use z-index. What am I doing wrong?

*Please just know I am still on my training wheels hence the tables.

Here is the link: http://donyafiorentino.com/dropdown.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a z-index to the `#drop_down_menu` css

```
#drop_down_menu {
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  clear:both; 
  margin:0px; 
  padding:0px; 
  text-align:left; 
  list-style-type:none; 
  text-align:center; 
  width:81px; 
  float:none; 
  left:0px; 
  top:0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. I think we  might be getting close... here's how it made it look - http://donyafiorentino.com/dropdown.html

Comment: The z-index was necessary but I'm realizing it's the mootools and jquery that are clashing.  I found this - http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries. And this - http://pixelsfromtheedge.com/2009/09/running-jquery-alongside-mootools/. But now sure how to implement these codes.

Comment: Alas! I have found this post on here to have answered my question! Thank you so much for your efforts though (fudgey)! --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict