# Jquery Mootools conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, onload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery and MooTools Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)

I'm running into some trouble here, I'm loading jQuery if it hasn't already been loaded in order to run my script. My script is inserted somewhere in the body tag on someone else's site. **My problem is that jquery conflicts with mootools just by loading it (jquery).**

Here is my script :

```
var attemptCount=0;

if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/.../1.6.2/jquery.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
function init(){
    if(arguments.callee.done) return;
    if(typeof jQuery!='undefined'){
         jQuery.noConflict();
         arguments.callee.done=true;
         // do some jquery stuff i.e. jQuery('...').etc...
    }
}
function waitForJQuery(){
    if(typeof jQuery!='undefined'){
        init();
        return;
    }
    if(attemptCount<100){
        setTimeout(waitForJQuery,100);
    }
    return;
}
if(document.addEventListener){
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init,false);
}
else if(document.attachEvent){
     waitForJQuery();
}
window.onload=init;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: you can use `script.onload = init;` and you don't need to use `addEventListener()` and `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery needs to be initialised prior to MooTools as the $ is an alias and jQuery has the ability to unbind this, probably worth a try if it isn't too difficult to do given your circumstance.

```
 <p>jQuery sets this paragraph's color to red but MooTools sets the border color.</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.x.x.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //no conflict jquery
    jQuery.noConflict();
    //jquery stuff
    (function($) {
      $('p').css('color','#ff0000');
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="moo1.x.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //moo stuff
    window.addEvent('domready',function() {
      $$('p').setStyle('border','1px solid #fc0');
    });
  </script>
```

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

Comment: This link may provide you a better outcome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict

Answer (score 0):

What mootools version are you using? Mootools will "automatically surrender" the $.

Do you have code for both jQuery and mootools written that is using the $?

If so you will need to manually find evey instance of the dollar sign in at least one of the languages and replace with the following

For jQuery $() becomes jQuery()

For Mootools $() becomes document.id()
// FYI this is the preferred coding pattern in moo Core and More since 1.3

Hope this helps!

PS if you complete this step there will be no conflicts :)

Answer (score -1):

here a approach you can try:

```
// Add jQuery
var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ.src = "http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js";
GM_JQ.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);

// Check if jQuery's loaded.

function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); }
else { $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); }
}

GM_wait();

// All your GM code must be inside this function.
function letsJQuery() {

alert("cheers");

}
```

Comment: This seems to be GreaseMonkey specific, which isn't what the OP asked...