# Javascript and JQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very expert in using javascript and jquery but I'm working with them for a client.
I have encountered a problem using two script: the first one makes a top panel sliding, the second is in a form. This one is used in order to hide or show a particular field basing on the drop down list choice.

I've found that if I disable the first script (the panel), the second script is working fine and vice versa. I tried usign JQuery noConflict() in the head of the page but nothing happened.

Here the code of the first script (sliding panel):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Lets make the top panel toggle based on the click of the show/hide link  
    $("#sub-panel").click(function () {
        // Toggle the bar up 
        $("#top-panel").slideToggle();
        // Settings
        var el = $("#shText");
        // Lets us know whats inside the element
        var state = $("#shText").html();
        // Change the state  
        state = (state == 'Nascondi' ? '<span id="shText">Entra</span>' : '<span id="shText">Nascondi</span>');
        // Finally change whats insdide the element ID
        el.replaceWith(state);
    }); // end sub panel click function
}); // end on DOM
```

Here the JS code for the form (hide/show field):

```
$document.addEvent('domready', function () {

    $('motivo_contatto').addEvent('change', function () {
        if ($('motivo_contatto').value == 'Invia CV') {
            $('upload_file').style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
            $('upload_file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    });
    $('upload_file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

});
```

Can anyone help me ? Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: The 'js code' would appear to be mootools?

Comment: Hi Marc B,
sincerely I don't know cause I found this script using Chronoforms. In the admin panel there's a button saing "JS code". I supposed it was a JavaScript one. But I'm not sure...

Comment: well, jquery uses .ready(), and mootools uses .addEvent('domready'). Check the page's headers to see exactly which libraries are being loaded.

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket and parenethesis in your second block.

Comment: Why do we need two different ways of document ready events. Can't we use one of them in both the places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using 2 different ways to add things to happen to the document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

and

```
$document.addEvent('domready', function() { ... });
```

maybe if you just use one it works; maybe the code below will work; I put it all in the first option to run code on document ready:

I edited below code and removed all mootools code; so it might work now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Lets make the top panel toggle based on the click of the show/hide link  
    $("#sub-panel").click(function(){
        // Toggle the bar up 
        $("#top-panel").slideToggle();  
        // Settings
        var el = $("#shText");  
        // Lets us know whats inside the element
        var state = $("#shText").html();
        // Change the state  
        state = (state == 'Nascondi' ? '<span id="shText">Entra</span>' : '<span id="shText">Nascondi</span>');          
        // Finally change whats insdide the element ID
        el.replaceWith(state); 
    }); // end sub panel click function

    document.getElementById('motivo_contatto').onchange = function() {
        if(document.getElementById('motivo_contatto').value == 'Invia CV') {
            document.getElementById('upload_file').style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('upload_file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('upload_file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}); // end on DOM
```

Comment: Hi Tom and thank you for the answer. 
I tried to use the script you have suggested but now none of the scripts are working. Any idea ?

Comment: I just edited; you might try it now, but can't you debug with firebug for example ?

Comment: I removed the mootools code and replaced it with pure javascript; maybe it'll work now. Maybe you'll have to remove mootools imports from your page also, I dunno. Doesn't seem like an option if you use mootools for other things also off course

Comment: Hi Tom, 
I'm using Chrome and in the debug panel I found this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEvent'

Comment: have you tried the last version in my post ? it doesn't use addEvent anymore.

Comment: Greeeat! It works perfectly. Can you please explain me briefly why the previous script wasn't working ? Thank you so much!

Comment: well, you were using mootools and jquery, 2 different javascript libraries; They both seem to use the dollar sign $ as a global variable, so that caused conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing up two different libraries. Not a good idea.

If you want to keep on following on that pattern, wrap one of the function on a different function and call if from another.

Like:

```
function moo()  {

    $('motivo_contatto').addEvent('change', function () {
            if ($('motivo_contatto').value == 'Invia CV') {
                $('upload_file').style.visibility = 'visible';
            } else {
                $('upload_file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        });
        $('upload_file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });

}
```

#### Then call it from another

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    moo(); // Call the moo function


    // Lets make the top panel toggle based on the click of the show/hide link  
    $("#sub-panel").click(function () {
        // Toggle the bar up 
        $("#top-panel").slideToggle();
        // Settings
        var el = $("#shText");
        // Lets us know whats inside the element
        var state = $("#shText").html();
        // Change the state  
        state = (state == 'Nascondi' ? '<span id="shText">Entra</span>' : '<span id="shText">Nascondi</span>');
        // Finally change whats insdide the element ID
        el.replaceWith(state);
    }); // end sub panel click function
}); // end on DOM
```

---

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2810523/295264) answer, if you want to use both libraries side by side