# Any specific order for Java script and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using one java script and one jquery in my html file in head tag, 
but my problem both the scripts are not working, i have used one slide show script and one nav menu script, in this both only one is working , is there any specific order to write these scripts ,
please find the below script order i have used , i am getting only slideshow. please help me out .

```
<script type="text/javascript">        google.load("mootools", "1.2.1");</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/MenuMatic_0.68.3.js" type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        var myMenu = new MenuMatic();
    });</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: _one java script and one jquery_? There is _conflict_ in your page. You can use jQuery `noConflict` method.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict) may help you.. conflict is coz of using mootools and jquery together

Comment: If you're including jQuery on your page anyway, why don't you use its cross-browser compatible `jQuery(document).ready(...)` rather than `window.addEvent('domready',...`?

Comment: I have used what u said jQuery(document).ready(function ($){var myMenu= new MenuMatic(); .. but no use ...

Comment: thanx guys i found the solution ...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have MooTools and jQuery loading on the same page which will work but you will have to replace the short hand jQuery function. jQuery uses $(function) shorthand for jQuery(function) and that shorthand notation could cause problems.

You will need to use the jQuery.noConflict() function anywhere jquery and it's plugins were using the $.

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(function () {
        $j('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi., can u please show,  how can i write the noconflict method to above two functions what i have written in my code, because i am new to javascript .

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how it would work in the code snippet you provided.