# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, var

I know there are many threads about this issue and i ve been looking for my specific case but i have not found anything relevant.

I am implementing this [javascript cashRegister effect](http://tommywebdesigner.com/untitle.html) in this [page](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Producto%20copy.html) but i get this error msg

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null"

It points to the raw 18 of the plugin.js:

```
var current_value = this.element.get('text');
```

What might cause this error? What i should try to do now?

Thanks

Comment: The reason for this is that this.element is null

Comment: ok, but it actually works in the other page, you know what i should try ?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is at this line:

```
var total = $('total');
```

The selector `total` means "find elements with the name 'total'". What you really want is to find the element with the *id* of "total," so do this instead:

```
var total = $('#total');
```

**Edit**:

I think some of the confusion stems from the fact that the `$` in the site you're referencing is the `$` from MooTools. In your page, you are including jQuery, which has an entirely different `$` object that behaves differently. I believe that `$('total')` is how you select an element by ID in MooTools.

I'm not sure how you can load both libraries without having naming conflicts, but if you can figure that out, make sure you're using MooTools to select the total instead of jQuery.

**Edit 2**:

After a bit of research (I'm unfamiliar with MooTools), I see that you could replace `$('total')` with:

```
document.id('total')
```

Comment: I have tried to modify it before but it s not the solution unfortunately, also because in the other page it works fine with this line var total = $('total');

Comment: @Manna That code is wrong, even if it doesn't break anything. It will ALWAYS return an empty array.  Either you just haven't noticed what it breaks yet, or it is unnecessary and should be removed.

Comment: that's true, but if i compare the two pages, the code is the same, and why it just works here http://tommywebdesigner.com/untitle.html?

Comment: See my update. I just noticed that the site you're referencing is using MooTools, and yours is loading both MooTools and jQuery.

Comment: This question may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict

Comment: Yes exactly, this might be the conflict reason, i have a look to the thread to figure it out the problem. So basically i need to add  in my jQuery scripts var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); and then replace every instance of $( with $j(..bit confused now :(

Comment: Or use my second suggestion; that would explicitly use MooTools, and you could still have your jQuery as-is without needing `noConflict`.