# Conflict between scriptmanager and rokbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager

I'm trying to use RokBox to display images on a page but the asp: scriptmanager is preventing it from working.

When I comment out the code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The RokBox script runs. The Rokbox code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rokbox/mootools-release-1.11.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="rokbox/rokbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="rokbox/rokbox-mt1.2.js"></script> 
<link href="rokbox/themes/dark/rokbox-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rokbox/themes/dark/rokbox-config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainjscript.js"> </script>
```

Any advice? These are things I'm really not familiar with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's becuase you are trying to use mootools and jquery together, you need to run jquery with `jQuery.noConflict();` have a look at these pages for more info:

[jQuery and MooTools Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries