# jQuery not working in live Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            jQuery('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jQuery('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
            jQuery('.scrolldown').fadeIn();
            }else {
            jQuery('.scrolldown').fadeOut();
            }
    });

    jQuery('.scrollup').click(function(){
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 900);

        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.scrolldown').click(function() {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(document).height()-jQuery(window).height() }, 900);
        return false;
        });

});
```

I tried this code for the page scroller for on a Wordpress site.  It works when I run from localhost not on the live site. Why isn't it working on the live site?

I get this error on the Javascript console (via Firebug):

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]   

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...
```

Comment: Are you importing jQuery, and doing so before the above code appears in the document?  Are there errors in the browser console?

Comment: I linked the <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> with the above script and also i getting error of

Comment: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]  

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]  

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
[Break On This Error]  

...pe);return e}x.each({parent:function(e){var t=e.parentNode;return t&&11!==t.node...

jquery.min.js (line 5)

Comment: Vicky, please add the error to your post and remove it from the comments.  It's too difficult to read in comments

Comment: I edited my question see above

Comment: Hmm...are you doing any other jQuery operations on the live site other than what is listed above?  Specifically anything involving jquery.parseJSON()?

Comment: I am Not sure Here is the live site link http://techstumbling.com I installed that plugin what i created (page scroller)

Comment: It looks like you are loading both MooTools and jQuery on the page. I'm not sure, but I would guess there's a conflict between those two libraries.

Comment: Thanks ReLeaf How Can i Overcome this issue. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your selector is failing

```
var store_cur_pos_top = $(".author_cont").offset().top;
```

As far as I can tell, there are no instances of $(".author_cont") on techstumbling.com.  As such, your .offset() call will fail

Same thing with:

```
$('whois').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
```

There is no object available for selector $('whois'). As ReLeaf mentioned, there may be a conflict between MooTools and jQuery

Some generic advice.  Solve these selector issues.  Clear your cache always to make sure you don't have stale content.  Start with these issues and then the rest will probably become more clear.

EDIT:

Here is a useful post about resolving MooTools/jQuery conflicts:
[jQuery and MooTools Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)

Comment: Thanks @David L Thanks for your Suggestions and for spending your valuable time to resolve my doubts. Much Appreciated your help.

Comment: @vicky You're welcome!  Good luck in resolving the issues!