# ZClip on a Joomla page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, zclip

I am having trouble with implementing zclip on my Joomla website. I created a test html page to get the zclip coding setup, and it works properly.

However, when implementing the code to my Joomla article (using no-editor), the SWF loads on top of the link as expected, but no actions are taken on the link when clicked. It won't copy the text to the clipboard nor will it redirect to another webpage. It works fine when on a standalone html document outside of Joomla.

What could be causing this to occur? Is there an incompatibility with zclip and Joomla? I am not sure how to diagnose, I tried many things and still cannot get it to work.

**UPDATE**: I figured out the solution. Joomla uses MooTools. If you use JQuery on the same page, you have to call the JQuery function using "JQuery" instead of the "$". Once I did this, ZClip worked fine. For some reason I had forgotten about the conflict between the two at the time.

Comment: ZClip requires some Javascript, so where are you adding the Javascript? Adding it to your editor will not work

Comment: I use no editor in Joomla, so it's pure unaltered input. I figured it out! It was a conflict between MooTools and JQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery and MooTools Conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)

Comment: @Sergio, you are correct! Had to use the word "JQuery" instead of "$" to correct it.