# Other jquery elements not supported when I apply this script in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use many `jQuery` elements in my page like toggle, accordion,
show hide and lightbox but when I apply this

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.solutoire.com/experiments/mootools/mootools.js">
</script>
```

my other jquery plugins are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Mootools and jQuery both use the dollar (`$`) sign.

You can get around this problem by using noConflict in jQuery:

`jQuery.noConflict();`

Just include that code at the beginning of your Javascript before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably happen a conflict between Mootools and jQuery since both of libraries are using `$`.

You can either use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your jQuery code or wrap your jQuery code inside:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Your code here
});
```

---

```
<script>
// Disable the $ global alias completely
jQuery.noConflict();

// For jQuery scripts
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias to jQuery
... here is your jQuery specific code ...

})(jQuery);

// For Mootols scripts
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias 
// to Mootools document.id
... here is your Mootools specific code ...

})(document.id);
</script>
```

Comment: its not working 
can u tell me other jquery accordion tab menu style

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

use

### [No Conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: its not working sir..
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                $('.login-wrapper').toggle("show");
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: it would be <script> $.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$('#showmenu').click(function() { $('.login-wrapper').toggle("show"); });
}); </script>

Comment: but its not working in my page
i use it but not working 
there no other way for this

Comment: My all script in my page
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.4.js"></script>
  
  

  <!---------------------------------------For fix div of comments---------------------------> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-lib-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#stop-top").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, center:true, className:"hey" });
    });
  </script>

Comment: <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#fix-on-top").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, center:true, className:"hey" });
    });
  </script>
  <!---------------------------------------For more-box--------------------------->
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#more-box').click(function() {
                $('.more-detail-container').toggle("slow","swing");
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                $('.login-wrapper').toggle("show");
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var accordion;
var accordionTogglers;
var accordionContents;

window.onload = function() {
 accordionTogglers = document.getElementsByClassName('accToggler');
 
 accordionTogglers.each(function(toggler){
  //remember the original color
  toggler.origColor = toggler.getStyle('background-color');
  //set the effect
  toggler.fx = new Fx.Color(toggler, 'background-color');
 });

Answer (score 0):

First check the url path.
Second make sure that you import this library after you have imported the jquery file.
If nothing of these is happening, then maybe there is a confict between the js files. So use noConflict() function.