# jquery codes overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

while trying to make that form it's working fine with that jquery code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>form SCCI</title>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.label_better.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".label_better").label_better({
          easing: "bounce"
        });
      });

    </script>

  <style>

    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
    background: #272D30;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'open sans';
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }
    .bl_form {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 150px;
    }

    .bl_form input {
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }

    .lb_label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    }

    .lb_label.active {
    color: #9F9;
    }

    </style>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/calendar.css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>

    <form action="/" class="long">
        <fieldset>

            <label for="date1">Date</label>
            <input id="date1" name="date1" type="text" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>


  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="header">




        <div class="btns">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-container">
        <form class="bl_form">
         <br> <input type="text" value=""  class="label_better" data-new-placeholder="Username" placeholder="Username" ></br>
          <br> <input type="email" value=""  class="label_better" data-new-placeholder="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address"></br>
          <br> <input type="password" value=""  class="label_better" data-new-placeholder="Password" placeholder="Password"></br>

        <br>  <input type="password" value="" class="label_better" data-new-placeholder="Confirm Password" placeholder="Confirm Password"></br>
        </form>
      </div>



    </div>


  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but while trying to add a date picker with jquery the codes conflict and the 2 jquery codes doesn't work together here is the date picker code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.rc4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
//<![CDATA[
    window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
        myCal1 = new Calendar({ date1: 'd/m/Y' }, { direction: 1, tweak: {x: 6, y: 0} });
        myCal2 = new Calendar({ date2: 'd/m/Y' }, { classes: ['dashboard'], direction: 1, tweak: {x: 3, y: -3} });
        myCal3 = new Calendar({ date3: 'd/m/Y' }, { classes: ['i-heart-ny'], direction: 1, tweak: {x: 3, y: 0} });
    });
//]]>
```

but the date picker working good if i remove the first code , but the two with each other , it's conflict and didn't work together

Comment: What two jquery codes? You have one script which uses jQuery, and one script that does not (and uses MooTools, apparently).

Comment: since both jQuery and mootools use `$` alias you will need to use `jQuery.noConflict()` ... see API docs. Alternatively stick to one library which is likely better the choice.

Comment: @charlietfl how can i add that the file which make the conflict is mootools.js but i can't drag it to the post because it's very large

Comment: @Amadan i can't drag it because it's very large but the one who make the conflict it's name mootools.js what should i do exactly with the other files ?

Comment: did you read the jQery API docs ? This issue has been around for years and lots has been written about it. If you don't understand it, then it is better not to mix the 2 libraries

Answer (score -1):

As Charlietfl pointed out in the comments, Mootools and jQuery have conflicts. See the following
[jQuery and MooTools Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)