# Something not allow me to show 2 things in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I made them on JSFiddle alone...you can see them by clicking the links...But when I put them together in one page...its not opening when I'm changing a javascript its working the other one...can some help me please...I think jquery.min.js is the problem..but how can I fix it

1st Code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            // On open, hide the original submit button
            $( this ).find( "[type=submit]" ).hide();
        },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Save",
                click: $.noop,
                type: "submit",
                form: "dialog-form" // <-- Make the association
            },
            {
                text: "Close",
                click: function() {
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    $( "#create-user" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
<form title="Show" id="dialog-form" action="GetRecent" method="GET">
<div class="squaredThree2">
<input  type="checkbox" id="squaredThree2" name="Show" />
<label for="squaredThree2">
<div style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 1.1em;color: #5a5a5a;margin-left:25px">Show</div>
</div>
<div class="squaredThree3">
<input  type="checkbox" id="squaredThree3" name="Show2" />
<label for="squaredThree3">
<div style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 1.1em;color: #5a5a5a;margin-left:25px;">Show2</div>
</div>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<a id="create-user" href="javascript:;">Show</a>
```

2nd Code:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HfszInbOhd8?rel=0&border=0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3" class="movieTrailer cboxElement buttn torrent">Watch Something
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[data-rel='movieSS']").colorbox();
    $(".movieTrailer").colorbox({iframe:true, width:705, height:580});
    $('.more-count span').html($('.comment').size());
});
```

Here is the links

[1st JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khafhs8d/4/)

[2nd JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvftz2c3/2/)

Comment: It looks like there's a conflict between jQuery UI and jQuery Colorbox. Just trying to load both of them in the same fiddle causes it to hang.

Comment: :/ Can I fix it..please tell me how if I can..thank you :D

Comment: It looks like something is loading MooTools. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict

Comment: @Barmar What to see?

Comment: I'm really not sure. All I know is that when I open the fiddle in Developer Tools, I see lots of `moo` scripts being loaded. There's also somehing called `prum.js`. I'm not sure what all these are for, but it seems like colorbox is loading them.

Comment: Colorbox loads only the one...youtube player...Jquery.min.js is the problem...If you know something to make jquery run only for a div id or class it will be helpfull...thank you

Comment: That's not how scripts work, they just load code into the browser's memory. They get attached to elements when you bind handlers and initialize widgets.

Comment: Pff ok..thanks for your time :/

Comment: Is there a fiddle with all on the same page?