# Lightslider and mootols not working together,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lightslider Jquery Code and mootols not working together if i remove jquery api code, so mootools working otherwise if i put jquery api code so then lightslider working (it is using jquery) but mootools not work then.

Mootools

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/script/mootools-1.2.1-core.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/script/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/script/slideitmoo-1.1.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvents({
    'domready': function(){
      /* thumbnails example , div containers */
      new SlideItMoo({
            overallContainer: 'SlideItMoo_outer',
            elementScrolled: 'SlideItMoo_inner',
            thumbsContainer: 'SlideItMoo_items',    
            itemsVisible: 5,
            elemsSlide: 2,
            duration: 150,
            itemsSelector: '.SlideItMoo_element',
            itemWidth: 158,
            showControls:1});
    },

  });
</script>
```

Lightslider

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet/lightslider.css" />
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="/script/lightslider.js"></script> 
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#content-slider").lightSlider({
                loop:true,
                 auto: true,
                keyPress:true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery and MooTools Conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict)

Comment: can u explain or point out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution i was trying myself then it is working.

Just need to change two things one api link location 2nd $ will be jQuery

Like this

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/script/mootools-1.2.1-core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/script/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/script/slideitmoo-1.1.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvents({
    'domready': function(){
      /* thumbnails example , div containers */
      new SlideItMoo({
            overallContainer: 'SlideItMoo_outer',
            elementScrolled: 'SlideItMoo_inner',
            thumbsContainer: 'SlideItMoo_items',    
            itemsVisible: 5,
            elemsSlide: 2,
            duration: 150,
            itemsSelector: '.SlideItMoo_element',
            itemWidth: 158,
            showControls:1});
    },

  });
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet/lightslider.css" />
    <script src="/script/lightslider.js"></script> 
    <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#content-slider").lightSlider({
                loop:true,
                 auto: true,
                keyPress:true
            });
        });
    </script>
```