# Difference between $('#id') and jQuery('#id')

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: $. vs. jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212602/jquery-vs-jquery)

I am too confused in this two types of jquery `$('#id') and jQuery('#id')`.

I have a form and in this form I have included so many jquery files for different functionality. All are working as expected. Now I want to include one more jquery for banners floating and I have configured all setting as displayed.

When I load the page It dispalys this following lines in console

`TypeError: $(".side-ads").scrollToFixed is not a function`

`TypeError: jQuery(".auth").autocomplete is not a function`

So I get confused in between this kind of confliction. Is there any way I can remove this confliction ??

Comment: `$ === jQuery`... in general there is no difference, unless you have `jQuery.noConflict()` somewhere. But I don't think we can help you much here since we don't know what files you are loading.

Comment: Show order of script tags referred jQuery, jQueryUI and your file

Comment: there are lots of files and because of that I can't list the files.

Comment: @FelixKling: with all due respect, $ vs jQuery is not the problem here. see, `TypeError: jQuery(".auth").autocomplete is not a function`

Comment: @naveen: I partly agree... but it's the title of the question and as I said in my comments, there is not much we can do other than saying the function does not exist. I could have voted to close as too localized as well.

Comment: so is there nothing I can do about this problem?

Comment: You can check order of appearance script tags referred to JavaScript files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ and jQuery both point to the window.jQuery object, so they are one and the same

the reason some scripts use jQuery instead of $ is to prevent conflicts with other libraries such as prototype or different versions of jquery which both also use the $ variable.

jQuery defines a nice solution to resolve conflicts: [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). By using this function you can define your own name, where jQuery will be accessible.

Comment: so why i am getting this type error???

Comment: how can i remove this confliction??

Comment: @Yogesh: Well, the error is clear...  maybe you are using two different jQuery versions in your page somehow and this messes up everything. You solve this by including the files you need and remove those that break your code. I suggest to remove all plugins, add them one by one and see which one causes problems.

Comment: And btw, this answer is not 100% correct. As I mentioned in my comment, `$` and `jQuery`  point to different objects if `jQuery.noConflict()` is used. See the top answer in duplicate question for a good explanation.

Comment: so if there is `jQuery.noConflict()` in code I have to remove this line? @FelixKling

Comment: @FelixKling could you tell me where can i see the duplicate question ?

Comment: See my second comment to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the type errors is most likely missing plugins. If you have them, have you included the scripts in your page?

The ScrollToFixed plugin is available [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2011/12/jquery-scrolltofixed/),
and Auto Complete is part of [jQueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: oh nick, you beat me to the answer 9 minutes back :) +1