# Why do some functions in jQuery start with `$.`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm following the beginners tutorial on jQuery called [How jQuery works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). After a couple basics a function is presented: `$.get( "myhtmlpage.html", myCallBack );`. I understand how it works and all, but I just don't understand why this function starts with `$.`, instead of simple being `get("myhtml... etc.`. Googling for it doesn't result in any results, I guess because Google doesn't take `$.` into account.

So my question, why do (some?) functions in jQuery start with `$.`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript possible duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $ is a shorthand for the jQuery object itself.

see this discussion:

[$ versus jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212602/versus-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Functions starting with `$.` are utility methods and not specific DOM elements. Examples include `$.ajax`, `$.each` etc.

Where as others like `$('#domID')` manipulates that specific DOM element like `$('#domID').fadeIn()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative would be to create dozens of *global* variables using the names of common words, and that is highly likely to conflict with other variables from other scripts on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The one should read "$.get" as: "$" is a namespace, "get" is a function within "$" namespace. Somewhat similar to static member functions in C++ and Java.