# how to use multiple lines of json string from $.get()

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I have a function that is loading multiple lines of Json string . I was trying to use that to populate a `select` element but its not working . I am trying to apply this in  a JQM website

Here is the function

```
function loadgeo2Adminii1(value,child,loading,vd,ponerfocus){
        if(parseInt(value,10) > 0){
                var url= UrlServer+'index.php?im_core=jsonSearchColonia&im_geo='+value;
                $('#im_texto_'+child).val('').selectmenu( "disable" );

                $('#im_'+child).val('');
                $.get(url,function(data){

                        data.sort(function(a,b){
                        if(a.id.toLowerCase()== vd[1].toLowerCase() || b.id.toLowerCase()== vd[1].toLowerCase() )bandera = 1;
                        var aName = remove_accents(a.label.toLowerCase());
                        var bName = remove_accents(b.label.toLowerCase());
                        return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));}
                        );
                        $( '#im_texto_g2').selectmenu( "enable" );

                        jQuery.each(function(data){
                        $("#im_texto_g2").find('#im_texto_g2-button').append('<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.label+'</option>');}); 

                },'json');
        }
        else{
        $('#im_texto_g2'.val('').selectmenu( "disable" );
        $('#im_'+child).val('');
                }
}
```

**Note:** I can see the response in the `Firebug` its showing a Json string containing lot of substring . Here is a **[link](http://pastebin.com/8JEaL2xx)** to  that substring

Also if you look at following part of my script

```
$( '#im_texto_g2'+child ).find('#im_texto_g2-button').selectmenu( "enable" );
   jQuery.each(data,function(i,item){
            console.log(item,i);
            $("#im_texto_g2").append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.label+'</option>');
        });
```

I am trying to populate the option tag here .

Thanks & Regards

Comment: please create a JSFiddle if possible

Comment: Are you really programming like this? It's a real mess there.

Comment: `jQuery.each(function(data){` ? Is the `jQuery` the name of your data array ? Sounds fishy (at best)

Comment: @boyd sorry bro I am really new to this . I know I write messy script I tried to format it please have a look

Comment: @BGR no JQuery.each() is a function I learned it from here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @BGR you can use jQuery instead $, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212602/versus-jquery

Comment: @mjimcua - The syntax is `jQuery.each(array, fn)` or `jQuery(array).each(fn)` NOT `jQuery.each(fn)`

Comment: add you html code as well

Comment: @BGR thanks for the advice I have updated the code now its working . I used like this  jQuery.each(data,function(i,item){}. But I will update it using the code you have mentioned

Comment: OK. I will make it an answer so that you can flag it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.each(function(data){` is an incorrect use of `jQuery.each()` the correct syntax is

- `jQuery(array).each(fn)` or
- `jQuery.each(array, fn)`